# Clearing all levels with minimum coins

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, computer-science, binary, combinatorial-game-theory

Thor is playing a game where there are N levels and M types of available weapons. The levels are numbered from 0 to N-1 and the weapons are numbered from 0 to M-1 . He can clear these levels in any order. In each level, some subset of these M weapons is required to clear this level. If in a particular level, he needs to buy x new weapons, he will pay x^2 coins for it. Also note that he can carry all the weapons he has currently to the next level . Initially, he have no weapons. Can you find out the minimum coins required such that he can clear all the levels?

Input Format The first line of input contains 2 space separated integers: N = the number of levels in the game M = the number of types of weapons

N lines follows. The ith of these lines contains a binary string of length M. If the jth character of this string is 1, it means we need a weapon of type j to clear the ith level.

Constraints 1 <= N <=20 1<= M <= 20

Output Format Print a single integer which is the answer to the problem.

Sample TestCase 1
Input
1 4
0101

Output
4

Explanation There is only one level in this game. We need 2 types of weapons - 1 and 3. Since, initially, Thor has no weapons he will have to buy these, which will cost him 2^2 = 4 coins.

Sample TestCase 2
Input
3 3
111
001
010

Output
3

Explanation There are 3 levels in this game. The 0th level (111) requires all 3 types of weapons. The 1st level (001) requires only weapon of type 2. The 2nd level requires only weapon of type 1. If we clear the levels in the given order(0-1-2), total cost = 3^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 = 9 coins. If we clear the levels in the order 1-2-0, it will cost = 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 = 3 coins which is the optimal way.

Comment: This is a covering problem you have to ask somewhere else.

Comment: Without reading the details, the text of the question appears to have been taken verbatim from an assignment, competition, or other test. I have no interest in doing your work for you. If you want help, please add context like details about your thoughts, attempts, what's giving you trouble, what you know, what you don't know, and/or where this question even comes from.